# Getting "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'" while inside of venv

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, python-3.10

Trying to use a CLI scraper that needs python 3.10
I installed python 3.10 and created the virtual environment using these commands:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y install python3.10
sudo apt -y install python3.10-dev python3.10-venv
python3.10 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

But then when I try to install the requirements

```
pip3 install --update -r requirements.txt
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/scraper/venv/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

While outside of the venv,

```
pip3 --version
```

Returns:

```
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

I'm running Pop Os 21.04

Comment: Modules need to be installed for each version of Python. Try installing `pip` for 3.10

Comment: Try `sudo apt -y install python3.10-dev python3.10-venv python3.10-pip`

Comment: @mechanical_meat @Alasdair `E: Unable to locate package python3.10-pip
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.10-pip'`

Comment: It's pretty new, 3.10... can you get by using 3.9 for now until someone makes the associated packages? There likely is another source for 3.10's pip, but I don't know for certain.

Comment: 3.10 is required as of recent update :/ @mechanical_meat

Comment: see if you can find a 3rd party package of it, maybe? i dunno what to say, OS package work will generally lag a little behind software releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

latest pip download

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.10
```

using the latest pip outside of the venv, `python3.10 -m pip`

told me the correct usage was

```
Usage:
/usr/bin/python3.10 -m pip <command> [options]
```

and that's what worked for me inside the venv

not sure if my python 3.10 is downloading to a weird directory or what